# enabling grails hibernate filters

Tags: hibernate, grails, filter, zk

Hi I am using the [Grails filter plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter)

I am trying to define a default filter as below

```
// Defined inside the Book entity
static hibernateFilters = {
    activeFilter(condition:'active=1', default:true)
}
```

When i run my integration tests the filter does not apply for dynamic finder methods like

```
Book.findAll()
```

If I add the below line in the BootStrap.groovy class

```
Book.enableHibernateFilter('activeFilter')
```

Then the filter is applied.

However when the application is run the filter is never applied, with or without the above code in BootStrap.groovy

Any ideas ?

After a little digging around this is what i have found

The hibernate filter plugin works well without the zkgrails plugin however the two cannot seem to work together :(

The below code snippet seems to be the problem for me.

I think we could have two issues here

1) Initially the execution gets to
    all(controller:'*', action:'*')

only once during application startup. I am thinking it should get there each time there is a new request and hence a new session.

2) Even if it somehow gets there after certain modification, I do not think it'll get past 
    all(controller:'*', action:'*')

composers are used in zkoss

```
class HibernateFilterFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                def session = grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession
                DefaultHibernateFiltersHolder.defaultFilters.each {name ->
                    session.enableFilter(name)
                }
            }
            after = {

            }
            afterView = {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging around I have come up with a workaround for the above problem

I basically extend the GrailsOpenSessionInViewFilter class

```
public class OpenSessionInViewFilterExt extends GrailsOpenSessionInViewFilter{
@Override
protected Session getSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory) throws DataAccessResourceFailureException {
    Session session = super.getSession(sessionFactory);
    for (Object filterName : DefaultHibernateFiltersHolder.getDefaultFilters()) {
        session.enableFilter((String) filterName);
    }
    return session;
}
```

}

I also have a entry in the web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilterExt</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.nthdimenzion.hibernate.ext.OpenSessionInViewFilterExt</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilterExt</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now each time a new session is created the default filters are enabled for it. I think this should work, however it'll be better if some change can be made in the zkgrails plugin or the hibernate filters plugin so that the two can co-exist in a single application :)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my Grails 2.5.X app I enable the hibernate filters in a web filter, i.e. I have this code in `grails-app/conf/Filters.groovy`

```
    class Filters {
        publishedContentFilter(uri: '/**'){
            before = {
                // enable the 'published filter in the Condition domain class
                Condition.enableHibernateFilter('published')
            }
        }
    }
```

In the integration tests in the plugin itself, the [filters are enabled in the setup method](https://github.com/gpc/grails-hibernate-filter/blob/master/test/integration/org/grails/plugin/hibernate/filter/CollegeFilterSpec.groovy#L14L17) of the test class.