# Hibernate Filter is not applied in Grails Service/Jobs

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My domain uses a hibernate filter like so:

```
class UserMapping {
    // Senseless App Logic here
    static hibernateFilters = {
        typeFilter(condition: "type = 'IDENTIFIED'", default: true)
        flagFilter(condition: "flags = 'ACTIVE'", default: true)
    }
}
```

They seem to apply fine when I use them in the controller however when I do the same findBy.. in my service or job, they are not applied. Any suggestions?

If it makes any difference, I invoke the findBy in a mixin.

This question seems related but its not exactly what I'm looking for: 
[enabling grails hibernate filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113436/enabling-grails-hibernate-filters)

Comment: In my case, I found that I forgot the "default: true" flag. :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time filters are automatically enabled is during web requests - this is due to the plugin's `HibernateFilterFilters` applying all enabled filters before each web request. But there's no global automatic filter logic - this would be impractical.

Instead use one of the approaches described in the [plugin documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter), e.g.

```
UserMapping.withHibernateFilters {
   ..code to execute
}
```

Comment: Burt, you already a champ. Thanks for answering two of my questions already!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found that I forgot the "default: true" flag. :o

We also have code in BootStrap.groovy which enables the hibernate filters:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    //Hibernate filters
    MyDomainObject.enableHibernateFilter('myFilter')
}
```

(I realize the question was already answered but I hope this helps someone else that's looking.)